# How to compare sum with the amount?

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, max, having

The table looks like this:

```
id, price, amount, transactionid
1, 5, 10, abc
2, 5, 10, abc
3, 20, 40, def
4, 20, 40, def
5, 15, 40, xyz
6, 20, 40, xyz
```

I want to compare the sum of the amounts with the amount and only select that are not equal.

Also in the example: 15 + 20 != 40

```
SELECT sum(price), transactionid FROM payment group by transactionid
```

Now I need the check with one of the amounts from a row and show only if is unequal.

Comment: Join the table with the subquery that calculates the sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT transactionid,
       SUM(price) total_price,
       MAX(amount) amount
FROM payment 
GROUP BY transactionid
HAVING total_price <> amount;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6d784e5e94a6d6e4700951dd3f24bd22).